# hide folders and extensions

Tags: php, file, variables

if have made a script that shows the contents of a folder but i wnat it not to show the folders and extensions.

does anyone know how to do this

```
// open this directory 
$myDirectory = opendir("../website");

// get each entry
while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {
$dirArray[] = $entryName;
}

// close directory
closedir($myDirectory);

//  count elements in array
$indexCount = count($dirArray);

// sort 'em
sort($dirArray);

// print 'em
// loop through the array of files and print them all
for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {
if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != "."){ // don't list hidden files
print("<ul id=\"navb\" class=\"page\"><a href=\"?mp=$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></ul>");
print("\n");
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need [`is_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) and [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

```
foreach(glob( $myDirectory . '/*') as $file)
{

  if( is_dir($file) || substr($file,0,1) == '.')
    continue;

  $info = pathinfo($file);

  echo '<li>' . $info['filename'] .'</li>';

}
```